# Visual Studio on Surface Pro SP1

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2010

So, I bought into the dream in the form of a surface pro and then I installed Visual Studio 2010 in the hopes of coding on the toilet.  However, I cannot get SP1 to install (from this link: [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34677)).  Has anyone successfully installed SP1 on the surface?

The error I get is:

> KB2736182 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.  Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225649 for more details.

If you follow the link you'll see this gem:

"Product of the product family Visual Studio 2010 or Team Foundation Server 2010 with Service Pack 1 applied"

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not installing VS2012. I have installed it on my surface pro with no problems. Have you tried installing with compatibility enabled.

Comment: Not a good one, actually.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, coding on the toilet.  Dreammmmyyy!